# Rails asset pipeline doesn't serve images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My Rails app doesn't serve images at all.

```
image_url('picture.jpg')
# will result in url(http://localhost:3000/images/picture.jpg)
# but should be url(http://localhost:3000/assets/picture.jpg)

image_tag 'picture.jpg'
asset_url 'picture.jpg'
# will result in the same url / path as image_url()
```

Neither http://localhost:3000/images/picture.jpg nor http://localhost:3000/assets/picture.jpg exists, while http://localhost:3000/assets/images/picture.jpg does.

Here is a gist of my application.rb and development.rb: https://gist.github.com/maximski/1ccb75f6f89c02932239

I am in development environment and I don't want to precompile files manually. The app is pretty much much newly generated so the configuration is almost completely set on default.

Comment: Required your `application.rb` and `development.rb` for investigate problem.

Comment: Added a gist for them.

Comment: in which folder you are storing images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appear if images doesn't exists in `app/assets/images` directory. Check that `app/assets/images/picture.jpg` file is exists.

Comment: My god, the images were stored in app/assets/images/images/picture.jpg so I didn't even notice it was the wrong directory. Thank you.